# Instantiating model in spring rest controller

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, autowired

I just need short explanation of one part of my spring web app that I don't understand exactly.

I have a simple mvc spring web app with `StudentController`. For data I have a class `StudentDataModelStub` that implements `IStudentDataModel` interface witch has some simple functions for working with data stored in the `List` in `StudentDataModelStub` class.

In `StudentController` class I have

`@Autowired
private IStudentDataModel model;`

When I delete `@Autowired` annotation I get `NullPointerException` which is expected, because I don't instantiate `StudentDataModelStub`. But how does the spring knows which class to instantiate `IStudentDataModel` with, because multiple classes can implement `IStudentDataModel` interface, and why `model` must be `@Autowired`?

This is one part of the `StudentDataModelStub` class.

```
public class StudentDataModelStub implements IStudentDataModel {

private final Map<Integer, Student> data = new HashMap<>();

@Override
public List<Student> getStudents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new ArrayList<>(data.values());
}

@Override
public Student getStudent(int id) throws IdNotFoundException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(!data.containsKey(id)){
        throw new IdNotFoundException("...");
    }

    return data.get(id);

}
```

Comment: Can you add the code for `StudentDataModelStub`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I delete @Autowired annotation I get NullPointerException which
>   is expected, because I don't instantiate StudentDataModelStub. But how
>   does the spring knows which class to instantiate IStudentDataModel
>   with, because multiple classes can implement IStudentDataModel
>   interface?

Spring container scans for the dependencies inside packages specified in `@Componentscan` (or `<context:component-scan>` inside xml) and injects them into the beans.

Now regarding which implementation to inject, you can find the below text from Spring doc (also look [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers)) (emphasis mine)

> **@Primary** **is an effective way to use autowiring by type with several**
>   i**nstances when one primary candidate can be determined**. When more
>   control over the selection process is required, Spring’s **@Qualifier**
>   annotation can be used. You can associate qualifier values with
>   specific arguments, narrowing the set of type matches so that a
>   specific bean is chosen for each argument.

In short, if multiple implementations are defined for the same `interface` then you need to tell the container which bean to be injected by specifying `@Primary` or `@Qualifier`.

> Why model must be @Autowired?

Your `StudentDataModelStub` class is not actually a Model (Entity) class, it is actually caching the student's data and returning it based upon the id.